# Image does not appear in webpage rendered by live-server

Tags: html, npm-live-server

I have a simple html file as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="images/test.png" alt="Your Image">
    </body>
</html>
```

My directory structure looks like this:

```
|   test.html
|   
\---images
        test.png
```

I fire up [`live-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server) from my Powershell 7 command line like this:

```
live-server .\test.html
```

It loads up without any problem, but the image does not appear in the rendered html. I have tried all variations of forward and backslashing in the file path provided to the `src` parameter but it doesn't help.

There is also an [issue](https://github.com/tapio/live-server/issues/409) about this on Github but which hasn't received any follow up.

How can I get local image files to render in the web page rendered by `live-server`?

Comment: did you try `./images/test.png`?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question : > I have tried all variations of forward and backslashing in the file path provided to the src parameter but it doesn't help.